# In rsyslog, how can I trigger an hourly email aggregating entries in one of our logs?

Tags: rsyslog

One of our apps has been configured to log certain errors to a log on a remote server using rsyslog. I've been asked to provide an hourly email that lists the errors logged within the last hour. I've looked at ommail, but it doesn't seem to do exactly this. Any suggestions on how best to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go low tech on this:

- put error messages in a separate file like

> ```
> *.error /var/log/error.log
> ```

- then rotate it hourly via [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)

From logrotate, you can run a script in the *prerotate* or *postrotate* part, where you can take the contents of the file and send them via Email.

[ommail](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/ommail.html) is more for sending logs matching a certain filter, so it would be hacky to make it send such "digests".